# Why doesn't html show the title of my book retrieved from sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, web

Hi everyone I'm trying to make a shooping cart for books.

I first imported a csv file with three books into store.db in a table named books.
[books table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekJDn.png)

Then I used a loop to print out all the titles of the book in books.html.

```
    <h1>Books</h1>
    {% for book in books %}
        <h2>{{ book["title"] }}</h2>
            <form action="/cart" method="post">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ book["id"] }}">
                <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

But in my webpage the titles don't show.
[webpage at books.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UINqs.png)

And after adding them to cart, cart.html is unable to show the books as well.

```
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
    <ol>
        {% for book in books %}
            <li>
                {{ book["title"] }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ol>
```

Below is my app.py from CS50:

```
    from cs50 import SQL
    from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session
    from flask_session import Session

    app = Flask(__name__)

    db = SQL("sqlite:///store.db")

    app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    Session(app)


    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        return render_template("books.html", books=books)


    @app.route("/cart", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def cart():

        # Ensure cart exists
        if cart not in session:
            session["cart"] = []

        # POST
        if request.method == "POST":
            id = request.form.get("id")
            if id:
                session["cart"].append(id)
            return redirect("/cart")

        # GET
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", session["cart"])
        return render_template("cart.html", books=books)
```

I am also confused regarding the use of

```
    book["title"] vs book.title.
```

After trying both, none of them resolves the issue.

Hope that someone will be able to help me on this.

Comment: In your index() function, what do you get if you print(books)?

Comment: @D.Hammaker, may I know where do I insert print(books) ?

Comment: after `books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books")`

Comment: @D.Hammaker I got [{'id': '1', ' title': ' Harry Potter'}, {'id': '2', ' title': ' Grishaverse'}, {'id': '3', ' title': ' Michael Singer'}]

Comment: Ok, it's caused by a typo: it's `' title'` and not `'title'`

Comment: @Swifty thanks! Can you also explain to me if there is any difference between using book.id and book["id"}? I changed them up and it seems to not affect the code.

Comment: As far as I know, since `book` is a dictionary, `book['id']` is correct, while `book.id` should throw an error.